# Filtering two php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have two arrays. I have combined both the arrays to output the total

1st array =

```
$farray = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [1] => Array ( 
                [ED] => 15 
                [EN] => 14
                )
         )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [2] => Array ( 
                [ED] => 5 
                [EN] => 10 
               )
          )
     )
```

2nd Array =

```
$tarray = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [1] => Array ( 
                [ED] => 45 
                [EN] => 50                  
            ) 
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [2] => Array ( 
                [ED] => 38 
                [EN] => 40
               )
         )
    )
```

The combination of the above two arrays:

```
  $all = Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [ED] => 60
                [EN] => 64                  
               ) 
            ) 
       [1] => Array ( 
            [2] => Array ( 
                 [ED] => 43 
                 [EN] => 50
                  ) 
             )
        )
```

Now I want to use the first array and the second array for inserting condition into the following codes:

```
$fscore = array_reduce(
$farray, 
function($farray, $item) {
    $id = key($item);
    $scores = $item[$id];
    $farray[$id] = array(
    "score" => array_sum($scores),
    "farray"=> min($scores)>=7      
   );
    return $farray;
   },
   array()
 );
```

The above attempt works and output the following (`print_r($fscore)`):

```
 Array ( 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [score] => 124
            [farray] => 1 
            ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [score] => 93
            [farray] => 0
            ) 
      )
```

But I want to put more conditions to it and combine with the `$tarray` like below:

```
 $all= array_reduce(
 $all, 
  function($all, $item) {
    $id = key($item);
    $scores = $item[$id];
    $all[$id] = array(
    "score" => array_sum($scores),
    "farray"=> min($scores)>=7
    //if tarray key==ED 23 else 26 for minimum `$scores`
    "tarray"=> min($scores)>='ED'? 23:26//ternary operator
   );
    return $all;
   },
   array()
 );
```

I don't know how to insert the $tarray. As stated earlier, without the $tarray, it works.

My attempts failed and does not output expected result. In this question I only used ED and EN (score keys) to save more space. The minmum score expected for $farray is greater than or equal to 7 whereas the minimum score expected for $tarray is 23/26. If the score key is ED in $tarray, the minimum score is greater than or equal to 23, else it must be 26. Depending on those conditions, I want to return true or false value. Please help. Below is my attempt:

```
    $farray = array(
            array (
                1=> array(
                    "ED"=>15,
                    "EN"=>14
                   )
               ),
            array(
               2=>array(
                    "ED"=>5,
                    "EN"=>10
                   )
                 )
               );

$tarray = array ( 
         array ( 
           1 => array ( 
                "ED" => 45, 
                "EN" => 50                  
            ) 
        ), 
         array ( 
          2 => array ( 
                "ED" => 38, 
                "EN" => 40
               )
         )
    );

$combine = array ( 
       array ( 
            1 => array ( 
                "ED" => 60,
                "EN" => 64                  
               ) 
            ), 
      array ( 
            2 => array ( 
                 "ED" => 43 ,
                 "EN" => 50
                  ) 
             )
        );

function filtertArray($value){
    foreach($value as $key =>$val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        foreach($v as $t=>$m){
            if($t=='ED'){
               return $m>=23;
            }else{
               return $m>=26;
            }            
        }
    }
  }
}
function filterfArray($value){
    foreach($value as $key =>$val){
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        foreach($v as $t=>$m){            
           return $m>=7;                   
        }
    }
  }
}

 $all = array_reduce(
     $combine, 
     function($combine, $item) use ($farray, $tarray) {
        $id = key($item);
        $scores = $item[$id];
        $combine[$id] = array(
              "score" => array_sum($scores),
              "farray"=> array_filter($farray,"filterfArray"),
              "tarray"=> array_filter($tarray,"filtertArray")
            );
         return $combine;
     },
     array()
   );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($all);
echo "</pre>";
```

This outputs:

```
E_WARNING : type 2 -- Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

The expected output from this code is:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [score] => 124
        [farray] => true//1
        [tarray] => true//1
        ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [score] => 93
        [farray] => false//0
        [tarray] => true//1
        ) 
  )
```

Comment: Why should `"tarray"=> min($scores)>='ED'? 23:26` generate `['tarray']=>1`?  Your expected output doesn't resemble the intent of your method.  This makes your question unclear.

Comment: @mickmackusa, this will generate true or false value.

Comment: Incorrect, the conditional will output `23` or `26`. [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6e45127e5f6d6cfcc04afbf3be13d83d5b82702)  I would like to help you if you can clarify your question details.

Comment: @mickmackusa, thanks very much. I have added more details to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, I am trying but from the first $farray subarray and the $tarray subarray.

Comment: @mickmackusa, the problem is I need to have 2 minimum value of scores from $tarray depending on the subarray key. The subarray Key ED will have a minimum value of 23 whereas EN will have 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I'd bother trying to spice this answer up with an `array_reduce()` call.  It is more important to comprehensibly deliver the correct comparisons and result.  You are certainly welcome to convert my series of foreach loops to array functions.

My latest edit added more sample score data with the newly advised keys.  The adjustment to `$fscore`'s `tarray` comparison is that now the lowest non-`ED` score is compared against `26`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/187f54a2890c1eb7a599539277eb4502b753d708))

```
$farray=[[1=>['ED'=>15,'EN'=>14,'MT'=>16,'MZ'=>20]],[2=>['ED'=>5,'EN'=>10,'MT'=>36,'MZ'=>30]]];
$tarray=[[1=>['ED'=>45,'EN'=>50,'MT'=>28,'MZ'=>27]],[2=>['ED'=>38,'EN'=>40,'MT'=>56,'MZ'=>60]]];

// generate $all
foreach($farray as $i=>$a){
    foreach($a as $n=>$scores){
        foreach($scores as $k=>$v){
            $all[$i][$n][$k]=$v+$tarray[$i][$n][$k];  // sum the relative scores
        }
    }
}
var_export($all);
echo "\n\n";

// generate $fscores
$sub23_keys=array_flip(['ED']);  // store list of keys that have lower score minimum
foreach($all as $i=>$a){
    foreach($a as $n=>$scores){
        $fscores[$n]['score']=array_sum($scores);
        $fscores[$n]['farray']=min($farray[$i][$n])>=7;  // check that both ED and EN scores are >=7
        $fscores[$n]['tarray']=min(array_intersect_key($tarray[$i][$n],$sub23_keys)) && min(array_diff_key($tarray[$i][$n],$sub23_keys))>=26;
    }
}
var_export($fscores);
```

Output:

```
// $all=
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'ED' => 60,
      'EN' => 64,
      'MT' => 44,
      'MZ' => 47,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    2 => 
    array (
      'ED' => 43,
      'EN' => 50,
      'MT' => 92,
      'MZ' => 90,
    ),
  ),
)

//$fscores=
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'score' => 215,
    'farray' => true,
    'tarray' => true,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'score' => 275,
    'farray' => false,
    'tarray' => true,
  ),
)
```

Comment: @TechMJ If this is not quite right, please explain where I went wrong so I can edit my answer.

Comment: @mickmackuse, thanks for the answer, it's almost correct, but completely correct from your understanding of the question. I need to add more check, There is not only ED and EN, there are MT, MZ but ED only makes an exception that it must be minimum 23 for the comparison, how do I put this? so this line: `$scores['ED']>=23 && $scores['EN']>26`, how can I change it like E.g. if(ED){ >=23 }else{ >=26}. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @TechMJ Have a look now.  Let me know.

Comment: you are amazing. let me be more curious. suppose `scores['ED']` and scores['ZA'] have the same minimum (23) considering the other remaining the same, how do we go about that? I will accept your answer. It's great. I am working on this for two days. thanks again.

Comment: @TechMJ Please clarify that last request.  Do you want a completely separate check which compares `ED` vs `ZA`?  or `ED` vs `lowest of all non-ED`?  Do you want to declare a new element for this or is this one more condition to determine the value of `tarray`?

Comment: @mickmackuse, thanks for your altruistic help. `ZA` OR `ED` or more (I will manually specify them) may have 23 as minimum score. the other (unspecified) will have 26 as minimum.

Comment: Manually like this: `min(array_intersect_key($scores,['ED'=>'','ZA'=>'']))>=23 && min(array_diff_key($scores,['ED'=>'','ZA'=>'']))>=26` ...or... you can store the lowkeys in a variable like this: `$lowkeys_23s=array_flip(['ED','ZA']);` and inject that array variable like this: `min(array_intersect_key($scores,$lowkeys_23s))>=23 && min(array_diff_key($scores,$lowkeys_23s))>=26`

Comment: I prefer the lowkeys. Thanks a million.

Comment: one last request, the $tarray could not have false value. So the condition >=26 not work. For example, if you put MZ=25 in the $tarray, the $tarray must return false, but it returns true. What might have been go wrong?

Comment: `min(array_intersect_key($tarray[$i][$n],['ED'=>''])) && min(array_diff_key($tarray[$i][$n],['ED'=>'']))>=26` gives me the correct solution.

Comment: Ah, yes, correct.  Sorry, I was having dinner with my family.  Good fix.